# PowerApp - Data isn't loading in the initial OnSelect

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I have a PowerApp application that looks like this

[PowerApp Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brugm.png)

the "Learn about" section is supposed to be populated with links from "colActiveRelatedLinks" collection and when I look at the "Items" property of the component I see that it is returning the data that I expect
[data returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nqxb.png)

But, the links fail to load in.

However, the links load correctly if I click on a new task in the left menu (for example// process new payment request) and then click back on the same "Process third party" task.

[loaded in properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEB0z.png)

So it appears there seems to be an issue with the initial "OnSelect" items in the task list as it selects the first one by default.

So how can I fix my app to have it load as expected the first time?

I tried clearing the collection before the ClearCollect like this

```
Clear(colActiveRelatedLinks);
ClearCollect(colActiveRelatedLinks, ForAll(Split(gblActiveTask.'Related Link Item', Char(10)) As i, LookUp('Related Links', 'Unique ID' = i.Value)));
```

But that didn't work for me

Comment: Are the Learn about links linked to left side task selection? How these two sections are interconnected?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so on your left menu, you have code to change a variable, or populate a collection etc... *(please correct me if I am wrong here)*.

You are correct in saying the initial loading of the gallery highlights the first item (or default item), but does not execute `OnSelect`.

The answer then, is to place some code in the page `OnVisible` to do what your `OnSelect` does.

For Example:

```
ClearCollect(
  colActiveRelatedLinks,
    ForAll(
      Split(First(colTasks).'Related Link Item', Char(10)) As i,
      LookUp('Related Links', 'Unique ID' = i.Value)
    )
);
```